# Parameterized PowerMock tests error while initializing mocks

Tags: unit-testing, junit, powermock, parameterized, rule

I am currently trying to run parameterized tests with powermock, however whenever I try to instantiate any kind of mock an exception is thrown. I am also using JDK 1.6.

Here is some sample code that recreates the problem for me

Test class:

```
package com.test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        mock(Runner.class);
    }

    @Parameters
    public static List<Object[]> data() {
        ArrayList<Object[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        arrayList.add(new Object[] {});

        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <powermock.version>1.5.1</powermock.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:30)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:19)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.<init>(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.loadImplementations(ClassPathLoader.java:145)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPluginImplementation(ClassPathLoader.java:110)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPlatformMockMaker(ClassPathLoader.java:106)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.<clinit>(ClassPathLoader.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:21)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<init>(MockitoCore.java:40)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:932)
    at com.lies.code.ParameterizedTest.test(ParameterizedTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:2014)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:885)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:713)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:98)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
    ... 55 more
```

Ever since I heard about the @Rule feature of powermock I have wanted to use it, but have run into similar issues like this one.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Thank you to anyone that takes the time to reply

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [PowerMockIgnore](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.5/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PowerMockIgnore.html)? The error that you have got seems to be with that of classloading, and you can defer loading of actual classes by specifying them in PowerMockIgnore annotation